# Serre's Vanishing Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, schemes, exact-sequence, sheaf-cohomology

I am having problem with the construction in [Serre's Vanishing Theorem](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XE). The proof begins with a general construction which I don't follow.

> Let $X$ be a scheme. $x \in X$ a closed point, $U\subseteq X$ an affine neighborhood. $Z=X \setminus U, Z'=X \cup \{x \}$. [There are](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3) quasi-coherent sheaves of ideals $I$, $I'$ cutting out $Z$ and $Z'$. Giving SES, 
>   $$ 0 \rightarrow I' \rightarrow I \rightarrow I/I' \rightarrow 0 $$

How does one obtain injectivitiy at $I' \rightarrow I$?

Comment: By definition, $I'\to I$ is the inclusion map.  Maybe you are not sure why $I'\subseteq I$?

Comment: Yes, I don't see how - now that you mentioned , I should review their constructions again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $I\subseteq\mathcal{O}_X$ is the subsheaf consisting of sections which vanish in the residue field at every point of $Z$, and similarly for $I'$.  Since $Z'\supseteq Z$, this means $I'\subseteq I$ (a section which vanishes on $Z'$ also vanishes on the smaller set $Z$).  The morphism $I'\to I$ in the exact sequence is then just the inclusion map, which is obviously injective.